# Getting error "does not contain a definition for" when running on Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i'm building my first UWP app but i'm having an issue. When i build and run my app on my computer - build for x86 - it all runs just fine. But when i try to run it on my Windows Phone (ARM), i get the following error:

> this.RootSplitView.DisplayMode    error CS1061: 'App' does not contain a
>   definition for 'RootSplitView' and no extension method 'RootSplitView'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Conquer_Companion
{
    using Views;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
    using Windows.UI;
    using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a sp              ecific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {

#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // This just gets in the way.
                //this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif
            // Change minimum window size
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(350, 200));

            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

            // Darken the window title bar using a color value to match app theme
            ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            if (titleBar != null)
            {
                //titleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
                titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
                titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

                Color titleBarColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["SystemChromeHighColor"];
                titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = titleBarColor;
            }

            if (SystemInformationHelpers.IsTenFootExperience)
            {
                // Apply guidance from https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/designing-for-tv
                ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);

                this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary
                {
                    Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Styles/TenFootStylesheet.xaml")
                });
            }

            AppShell shell = Window.Current.Content as AppShell;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (shell == null)
            {
                // Create a AppShell to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                shell = new AppShell();

                // Set the default language
                shell.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

                shell.AppFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }
            }

            // Place our app shell in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = shell;

            if (shell.AppFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored, navigate to the first page
                // suppressing the initial entrance animation.
                shell.AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(LandingPage), e.Arguments, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
            }

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Conquer_Companion.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Conquer_Companion"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx://Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Can you guys help me figure out whats causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rebuild first and then make sure you do not have any other errors. Some errors may prevent comping other classes which leads to misleading errors like this one.

Comment: I have done that, cleaned the solution, then rebuild arm, then debugged on the device again, but the error still remains.

Comment: Look at the output window. Is it the only error?

Comment: try to add Reference "Right click on reference > add reference > Universal windows > Extensions > and add 'Windows Mobile Extension for UWP' for your respective SDK e.g 15063 " if it is not resolved your problem try to show your referenced styles and mention your sdk version you used so i can build your project and check

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I cannot find this reference in the list, what should i do in this case?

Comment: Which version of sdk of windows 10 you are using e.g 10240,10586, 14393 you should add respective version of uwp mobile extension you will definitely one